# SharedPreferences Not Saving after creating separate class for it

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

Iam developing an App where iam saving the values in SharedPrefernces. I've created a separate class ***SharedPreferenceforAlarm*** for setting
or getting the values stored in SharedPreferences. To set or get the stored values, iam calling the class object from different activities.

The problem which iam facing is that the values are not saving correctly.

For example(see the code):

Default value for ***alarmisSet: False***

Default value for ***alarmName : No Alarm***

If iam calling setAlarm(this, true) from any activity, the Log what iam getting is
***"SHAREDPREFERENCES, Alarm is set: false;"***

Same case if iam calling ***setAlarmName()***, default ***alarmName*** is printing not the one iam giving.

Its worth mentioning that i've created a ***setupHelp*** activity  for the first run of the app. When iam installing the app and running it, the ***setuphelp*** activity is running. The second time, that ***setuphelp*** is not shown. This means that ***setFirstRun()*** and ***getFirstRun()*** of the class ***SharedPreferencesforAlarm*** is working correctly but not after that.

Its also worth mentioning that while setting up the default values for ***alarmisSet*** to ***false*** and ***alarmName*** to ***No Alarm***, the Logcat shows shows the output correctly.

PS: I've checked on different PC's but again with no success.

```
/*****************************Shared Preference Class**************************************//


public class SharedPreferencesforAlarm {

public static final String TAG = "SHAREDPREFERENCES" ;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "Alarm" ;
public static final String firstRun="Firstrun";
public static final String alarmisSet="alarmisSet";
public static final String alarmName="alarmName";



public SharedPreferencesforAlarm() {
    super();
}

public void  setFirstRun(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences mySettings;
    mySettings = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor=mySettings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(firstRun, true);
    editor.commit();
}

public Boolean getFirstRun(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences mySettings;
    mySettings = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return(mySettings.getBoolean(firstRun, false));
}

public void setAlarm(Context context, Boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences mySettings;
    mySettings = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor=mySettings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(alarmisSet, value);
    editor.commit();
    Log.d(TAG,"Alarm is Set:"+value);
}

public Boolean getAlarm(Context context, Boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences mySettings;
    mySettings = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return(mySettings.getBoolean(alarmisSet, value));

}


public void setAlarmName(Context context,String name) {
    SharedPreferences mySettings;
    mySettings = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = mySettings.edit();
    editor.putString(alarmName, name);
    editor.commit();
    Log.d(TAG, "Alarm Name:" + name);
}

public String getAlarmName() {
    SharedPreferences mySettings;
    mySettings = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return(mySettings.getString(alarmName, null));

}
```

}

```
    /***********CODE FOR CALLING THE SHARED PREFERENCE CLASS FROM ANY ACTVITY*****************************//
SharedPreferencesforAlarm sharedPreferences = new    SharedPreferencesforAlarm(); //creating the object
sharedPreferences.setAlarm(this, true);
sharedPreferences.setAlarmName(this, alarmName.getText().toString()); //alarmName is a TextView
```

Comment: I don't see any problem in this code. Please post your complete code in the activity.

Comment: Iam calling the SharedPreference class from many activity. Iam creating the object by calling the constructor in onCreate() of activity. After creating the object, calling the setAlarm() or getAlarm() fucntion through that object.

Comment: I've updated the question, it will give a more clear picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the problem: wrong assumption about `sharedpreferences.getBoolean()` method.

I was assuming that

```
getBoolean(parameter, true)
```

return true if the parameter is true and second parameter is true and false if the parameter value is false and the second argument is true but actually it returns the parameter value only.

Answer (score 0):

First, make your class abstract, and its methods static, like this:

```
public abstract class SharedPreferencesforAlarm {

    public static final String TAG = "SHAREDPREFERENCES";
    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "Alarm";
    public static final String alarmisSet = "alarmisSet";
    public static final String alarmName = "alarmName";

    public static void setAlarm(Context context, Boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences mySettings;
        mySettings = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Editor editor = mySettings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(alarmisSet, value);
        editor.commit();
        Log.d(TAG, "Alarm is Set:" + value);
    }

    // repreat for other classes
}
```

Then, you can call your methods like this, without creating a new SharedPrefs object all the time:

```
SharedPreferencesforAlarm.setAlarm(this, true);
SharedPreferencesforAlarm.setAlarmName(this, alarmName.getText().toString());
```

I'm doint it like this in my projects, and is the only difference i can see at the moment.

Comment: but how you will instantiate it. Isn't it going to give null pointer exception?

Comment: I edited my answer, got a typo. Sorry for that.
Since your class is abstract, you dont have to instanciate it.

Comment: but i think it will give an error. We can call the method of class without creating the object if the method is static. Isn't it?

Comment: Damn, i forgot the classes' methods have to be static too. My bad...
So please make them static and try it out, i will edit my answer.

Comment: I've updated the question, it will give a more clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

```
  You write your code like this you have problem with Editor class.



public void setAlarm(Context context, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences mySettings;
    mySettings = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySettings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(alarmisSet, value);
    editor.commit();
    Log.d(TAG,"Alarm is Set:"+value);
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question, it will give a more clear picture.

Comment: Hi, i can see you code please try this.  

public void setAlarm(Context context, boolean value) {
    SharedPreferences mySettings;
    mySettings = context.getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySettings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(alarmisSet, value);
    editor.commit();
    Log.d(TAG,"Alarm is Set:"+value);
}